# Schema Directive Support in GraphQL With Code First Approach

Tags: graphql, nestjs

Custom schema directive in graphQL seems to be a good way to handle fine grained authorization on query and objects as well as fields, however, I only see examples on schema first approach so far. I read somewhere that it is not supported in code first approach. Please confirm if this is true? If not, what is the syntax to apply the directive on objects, fields etc. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it can help but please can you take a look at: https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/directives#code-first